# Formatting a double value within the toString() method (with respect to the decimal)

Tags: java, string, formatting, format, double

This is a fairly simple question. I have a class of objects `Item` which constructs the objects declared in the `TestItem` class. The overridden `toString()` method utilises the `DecimalFormat` class in order to format my double value `price`. When my `toString()` method is written as such, my output is produced in this fashion:

[image: item output]

The *only* modification in formatting I desire is alignment with respect to the decimal, how do I achieve this?

```
     public String toString() {
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
        String add = "";
        if(itemName.length() < 7) {
            add = "\t";
        }
        return itemID + " \t " + itemName + add + "\t" + inStore  + "\t   $" + format.format(price);
    }

public class TestItem {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Item list[] = { new Item(1011, "Air Filters", 200, 10.5),
                        new Item(1034, "Door Knobs", 60, 21.5),
                        new Item(1101, "Hammers", 90, 9.99),
                        new Item(1600, "Levels", 60, 19.99),
                        new Item(1500, "Ceiling Fans", 100, 59),
                        new Item(1201, "Wrench Sets", 55, 80) };
        printMovies(list);
    }

    public static void printMovies(Item list[]) {
        System.out.println("itemID\t itemName\tinStore\t    price");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        for(Item token : list) {
            System.out.println(token);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This isn't the full code; only what is relevant.

Comment: First problem: the use of `double` for currency values. `BigDecimal` is much more appropriate. Which version of Java are you using? `String.format` may be able to make *all* of this simpler.

Comment: @JonSkeet Not sure, how would I check what version I'm using?

Comment: I've no idea from within BlueJ, but I'd expect it to be fairly easy to find somewhere in the environment settings...

Comment: @JonSkeet No idea; have you got any idea how I might perform my desired task?

Comment: You can try the code I've given... if it works for you, there we go..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.format` to control the format in general. Unfortunately I can't see any way of combining that with a custom pattern directly, but you can compose them. For example:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showPrice(new BigDecimal("123.456"));
        showPrice(new BigDecimal("11.12"));
        showPrice(new BigDecimal("10.5"));
        showPrice(new BigDecimal("1.5"));
        showPrice(new BigDecimal("0.5"));
    }

    static void showPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        String text = String.format("Price: $%5s", format.format(price));
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Price: $123.46
Price: $11.12
Price: $10.50
Price: $ 1.50
Price: $ 0.50
```

Note that:

- The `$` signs are still aligned (the space comes *after* that)
- The "wide" price doesn't look good, but there's not much you can do about that
- Using `"0.00"` instead of `"##.##` means the last price is "0.50" rather than ".5"

You can use `String.format` to format *all* of your data, controlling the width of fields with the format specifier. You might want to use spaces instead of tabs to make it easier to ensure it's aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `00.00` as the pattern and after that you get for example a string like 09.53
Then you look, if the first and the second chars are '0' and if so, replace them with a space. You should use a new string object for that matter, because you can't change chars of a string.

Comment: The `#` will *not* produce a leading 0. I suspect you mean `00.00` as the pattern.